# Script misaligns table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have basic table

**html**

```
<table id="damageList">
  <tr>
   <td>#</td>
   <td>Type</td>
   <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which I'm trying to fill by data dynamically with

**js**

```
function addDamage(){
  var trA= "<tr>";
  var trB= "</tr>";
  var td1= "<td>"+nmbr+"</td>";
  var td2= "<td>"+type+"</td>";
  var td3= "<td><a href='#confirmDialog'>X</a></td>";

  $("#damageList").append(trA, td1, td2, td3, trB);

  nmbr++;
}
```

(the variable nmbr is numbering of lines and goes from 1, type is solved dynamicaly elsewhere)

The problem is, I'm not getting proper table.

What I get is this:

```
<table id="damageList">
  <tr>
   <td>#</td>
   <td>Type</td>
   <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>K</td>
  <td>
   <a href="#confirmDialog">X</a>
  </td>
</table>
```

Could somebody please tell me, where  did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM doesn't work that way. You can't append opening/closing tags separately. You should pass a full string representation of an element. What happens is:

```
$("#damageList")
     .append(trA, // append a TR, since `<tr>` can be parsed as an element
             td1, // append a TD
             td2, // append a TD
             td3, // append a TD
             trB // append a closing `</tr>` tag, silently fails
     );
```

You can concatenate the strings and then pass it to jQuery.

```
$("#damageList").append(trA + td1 + td2 + td3 + trB);
```

Also note that you should wrap the rows with a `tbody` element and append the generated rows to it:

```
$("#damageList tbody").append(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing you function to the following:

```
function addDamage(){
  var val = [
     "<tr>",
     "<td>"+nmbr+"</td>",
     "<td>"+type+"</td>",
     "<td><a href='#confirmDialog'>X</a></td>",
     "</tr>"
  ].join('');

  $("#damageList").append(val);

  nmbr++;
}
```

jQuery is automatically handling your first unclosed `<tr>` and creating `<tr></tr>` before appending it to `#damageList`. Then it appends three `<td>`'s to `#damageList`. Finally, it is discarding the closing `</tr>` since it doesn't know how to handle it. Concatenating the values together before appending will solve your issue.